# how to use selected data with angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, frontend, backend

I am a beginner both in Angular and programming generally,
i am currently using angular and i need help on how to use selected data.

for example, i want to be able to use a personnel-number [see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m90BW.png) and send it to the backend.
I need help on how to achieve this and would appreciate links to helpful learning resources. Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello. Adding relevant code snippet instead of image is more helpful.

Comment: If i get you, you're asking for help on how to get data into your application from an external source, if I'm correct, is the data in JSON format or from an image such as the one in your sample

Answer (score 1):

Backend interaction with angular is carried out with **HttpClient** under **@angular/common/http** namespace. Make sure you have imported the **HttpClientModule** in your **AppModule**

After that you will make HttpClient service available in your component through Dependency Injection by declaring it as a parameter of your constructor. Something like

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){
}
```

HttpClient provide **get, post, put, delete**  methods to interact with server, based on the serverside api you are calling. [Angular official website](https://angular.io/) has a very detailed documentation on the features of HttpClient. Please find the link

> https://angular.io/guide/http

For example if you are making a get request, you'll simply have to provide the url of your backend service with parameter appended like this

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(`http://yourapiurlwillgohere?phoneNo=${this.phoneNumber}`).subscribe(res=>{
console.log('server side response is');
console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: yes exactly. i can make a get- and post-request to receive data from database and to add data. that is the get.     getBorrows(): Observable<Borrow[]> {
      
    const url = (`${this.borrower_Url}`);
    console.log(url);
    return this.httpClient.get<Borrow[]>(url).pipe(tap(
      _=> console.log("borrows loaded")
      
    ));
  };